# Mac OSX system with a non-Mac mouse

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, mouse-buttons

My operating system is Mac OSX Leopard, but I am using a non-Mac, two-button mouse.  How do I enable the left button to automatically open files with a double click?

Answer (score 2):

The left button should work that way automatically; USB and Bluetooth mice use a standard interface that works the same everywhere.

Comment: It was working and just stopped.  Now I have to double click the file, then right click to get a flyout menu with open file.  Frustrating!

Comment: In that case, you may want to go into System Preferences > Mouse and see if adjusting the double-click speed helps; if it's set too fast then you may have trouble getting a double click to be interpreted properly instead of as two single clicks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though there may be a problem with your mouse as opposed to an issue in the OS. I've seen it before as mice get older the buttons will begin to stick in the "down" state and therefore not register a click properly. You could try cleaning around the buttons as best you can, or even just try pulling up on them ever so slightly (not enough to break the button off obviously). This may release them enough to register clicks properly once more. Depending on the cost of the mouse, it may be easier to replace it with another one.